# Upgrading vs building new items

Tags: clash-of-clans

I just reach TH 9. What are the benefits of upgrading first before building new items? I guess one is the base layout wouldn't have to be changed.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a chart to help you decide.

**Building**

Pros:

- You'll cover more defense area
- Little more Firepower

Cons:

- Costs a lot to upgrade well
- New base layout

  - If not upgraded yet, weak defense spot

**Upgrading**

Pros:

- Stronger Defence
- Same base layout
- Doesn't cost as much as upgrading up a new tower

Cons:

- Same area coverage

Comment: One extra pro to building new: If you build it after war mathcing but before prep day is over, you will have more weight than you were matched up as.